# Setting a method for all attributes in Python

Tags: python

I created this class

```
class Things:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    
    def plot(self,name):
        px.scatter(getattr(self, name)).show()
```

In this example one can plot the attributes `a` or `b` calling

```
thing = Things([1,2,3,4], [2,2,2,2])
thing.plot('b')
```

But I want to be able to plot the attributes using the following syntax:

```
thing.b.plot()
```

or

```
thing.a.plot()
```

Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For this, you can use one more supporting class to do this thing.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class PlotAttribute:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def plot(self):
        plt.scatter(range(len(self.data)), self.data)
        plt.show()

class Things:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = PlotAttribute(a)
        self.b = PlotAttribute(b)
```

Now you can do this

```
thing = Things([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 2, 2])
thing.b.plot()  # Plots the 'b' attribute 
thing.a.plot()  # Plots the 'a' attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a inner class inside your own class. one way to do that is

```
import plotly.express as px

class Things:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = self.Innerclass(a)
        self.b = self.Innerclass(b)

    class Innerclass:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data

        def plot(self):
            px.scatter(self.data).show()

plots = Things([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5])
plots.a.plot()
plots.b.plot()
```

Comment: @slothrop yes you are right it is inner or nested class not subclass technically. Updated the code